# Custom Fitler android

Tags: java, android

Мне необходимо отфильтровать данные в зависимости от вводимых значений в EditText.
Ниже код фильтра который уже написан но работает он не совсем корректно

Собственно InfectionModel

```
public class InfectionModel implements Serializable {
    private String id;
    private String content;
    private String title;
    private String prew;
    private String date;
    private String url_img;
}
```

И вот так у меня он хранится:

```
 private ArrayList<InfectionModel> im = ArrayList<InfectionModel>
```

Написал свой фильтр

```
  public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count == 0) {
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }else{
                im = (ArrayList<InfectionModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                results.values = im;
                results.count = im.size();
            }else{
                ArrayList<InfectionModel> filter_items = new ArrayList<InfectionModel>();
                for (InfectionModel item : im) {
                    if (item.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        filter_items.add(item);
                    }
                }
                results.values =  filter_items ;
                results.count = filter_items.size();
            }
            return results;
        }
    };
}
```

Вот только когда символы стираются - элементы перестают фильтроваться

Comment: Пожалуйста уточните свой вопрос

Comment: Как можно отсортировать данные на основе вводимых значений в текстовое поле?

Comment: вы хотите отсортировать введенные в поле данные?

Comment: Данные берутся из ArrayList и выводятся в ListView, в ArrayList хранится InfectionModel

Comment: А что тогда хранится в EditText?

Comment: EditText поле в которое вводится текст по которому должен сортироваться список ListView<InfectionModel>

Comment: пожалуйста, покажите InfectionModel. где храниться список? как он выводится? вы хотите сортировать или фильтровать этот список?

Comment: пардон, поправочка. фильтровать список